# Which is faster: in_array or database queries?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Which is faster?

1. I store the SQL results in an array - which means 1000 or more IDs. And then I use in_array() function 30 times to find out MyID is in the database.
2. I check MyID is in the database and repeat it 30 times.

#### Test results:

```
48 records (MyID)

Array count: 1704 (ID) (Table size: 100 000)

Delta time:

Method 1: 0.0075759887695312

Method 2: 0.0038831233978271
```

Comment: Have you tried timing it on your own?

Comment: It will be easy enough to detect the time needed for any approach, rather than asking

Comment: Why not just search the database for all your ids, and then make an in_array in that? like `'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE MyID IN ('.implode(',', $ids).')'`

Comment: Have you tried using a **single** query? E.g. `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (1,5,2,7);`. This will return all rows from the database for users with id 1, 5, 2 and 7 **if they exist**

Comment: Not yet. And I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493105/phps-in-array-vs-mysql-select

Comment: @EsbenTind LOL, you beat me to it :D

Comment: <<IN>> is the slowest.Try to avoid if possible.

Comment: @ Esben, thaJeztah: It's a bit complicated. There are several related tables, so that is not a problem MyID isn't in a table. But (sometimes) I should know about it. 
But thank you anyway

Comment: Please try both approaches, and then answer your own question for the illumination of others.

Comment: @Andy Lester: I will try

Comment: Just to expand on the answer I gave to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493105/phps-in-array-vs-mysql-select the problem is that php arrays are implemented as hashmaps - hence for arrays with few values the cost is O(1) but this tends to O(N) as the number of collisions increases - while an indexed table in a database should give O(log(N)) consistently

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely say that getting all ID's in array at one go will be much faster that querying MySQL server 30 times.

Comment: ...but there are alternatives.. See the comments

Comment: Thank you! What about the memory? How many integers may I have in that array for an acceptable performace? (I have limited resources..)

Comment: well that depends on many things.... Integers 32 or 64 bit? If 32 bit you can automatically have twice as much than if it was 64 bit. Depends on how much and what type of memory available. No black or white answer really :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a (key,value) associative array instead (actually all arrays are associative in PHP but this is not the point). Set the *keys* of the array as ID, and each value is (for instance) 1.

```
$ids = array();
For all ID from database {
   $ids[ ID ] = 1;
}
```

To test if  ID is in the array

```
if (isset($ids[ ID ])) {
   // yes it is 
}
```

using an array this way is very fast as internally the keys are stored as a tree - [the search complexity is ~ O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473989/list-of-big-o-for-php-functions)

Comment: Yes, it is faster :)

1.: 0.0079531669616699;

1.1 this: 0.0025970935821533;

2: 0.0030391216278076;

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your proposed solutions seem right. You should look in to MySQL's [IN clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm). With this, you can `WHERE` for multiple values in a single query, like so:

```
SELECT something FROM table WHERE id IN(1, 4, 5, ...)
```

Comment: But I need all 'something'.
I show the datas of Table1, by ID. And if I have some more data in Table2 with the very same ID, it modifies things...

I think it would be better to use JOINTs in query, but the datas of Table1 are in the memory already.

Comment: Yes, sounds like you should be using a JOIN then, perhaps something like `SELECT something FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.foreign = table2.id WHERE table1.id IN(1, 2, 3, ..)`